# liquibase gradle plugin could not find method

Tags: gradle, jhipster, liquibase

I'm trying add liquibase plugin to JHipster project but i get error:

```
Error:Could not find method liquibase() for arguments [org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:3.6] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Please tell me, how can i resolving this promlem?

Code build.gradle:

```
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release" }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${spring_boot_version}"
        classpath "org.springframework.build.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.7"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:1.2.4"
        //jhipster-needle-gradle-buildscript-dependency - JHipster will add additional gradle build script plugins here
    }
}

plugins {
    id "org.liquibase.gradle" version "1.2.4"
    //jhipster-needle-gradle-plugins - JHipster will add additional gradle plugins here
}


apply plugin: "org.liquibase.gradle"
```

Comment: Add in dependencies : classpath "org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:3.6"

Answer (score 1):

I generated my project with Jhipster too and had to comment the line

`apply from: 'gradle/liquibase.gradle'`

and add in dependencies

`classpath "org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:3.6"`.